# Три знака после запятой в цикле

Tags: python, циклы

уважаемые форумчане и разработчики,

Проблема:
Открываю текстовой файл, разбиваю на список, идут расчеты с элементами списка через циклы.
Потом приходит время записывать построчно результаты циклов в текстовой файл. Делаю так:

```
a = open(text.txt, "w")
size = длинна списка

for i in range(0,size):
    a.write("значение y=" + str(y[i]) + "\n")
```

Вопрос: помогите, пожалуйста, понять, как можно записывать результаты цикла построчно, чтобы у полученных цифр была точность 3 знака после запятой?

Пробовал форматы, но не понимаю как их прилепить именно в цикле

Comment: `a.write(f"значение y={y[i]:.03f}\n")` или `print(f"значение y={y[i]:.03f}", file=a)`

Comment: @MaxU а почему `.03`, а не `.3f` ?

Comment: @splash58, можно `.3f` ;)

Comment: @MaxU я думал, что чкго-то не знаю :)

Comment: @MaxU спасибо, заработало)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы записать число с указанной точностью, вы можете воспользоваться этим кодом:

```
# Входные данные
from math import pi, e
y = [1, 2, .32, .4124, pi, -2, 0, e]

# Работа программы
a = open('text.txt', "w")
size = len(y)

for _ in range(0, size):
    a.write(f"значение y={y[i]:.03f}\n")
a.close()
```